# Trouble getting right values against each item

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to parse the item `names` and it's corresponding `values` from the below snippet. `dt` tag holds `names` and `dd` containing `values`. There are few `dt` tags which do not have corresponding `values`. So, all the `names` do not have `values`. What I wish to do is keep the `values` blank against any `name` if the latter doesn't have any values.

These are the elements I would like to scrape data from:

```
content="""
<div class="movie_middle">
    <dl>
        <dt>Genres:</dt> 
        <dt>Resolution:</dt> 
        <dd>1920*1080</dd> 
        <dt>Size:</dt> 
        <dd>1.60G</dd> 
        <dt>Quality:</dt> 
        <dd>1080p</dd> 
        <dt>Frame Rate:</dt> 
        <dd>23.976 fps</dd> 
        <dt>Language:</dt>
    </dl>
</div>
"""
```

I've tried like below:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(content,"lxml")
title = [item.text for item in soup.select(".movie_middle dt")]
result = [item.text for item in soup.select(".movie_middle dd")]
vault = dict(zip(title,result))
print(vault)
```

It gives me messy results (wrong pairs):

```
{'Genres:': '1920*1080', 'Resolution:': '1.60G', 'Size:': '1080p', 'Quality:': '23.976 fps'}
```

My expected result:

```
{'Genres:': '', 'Resolution:': '1920*1080', 'Size:': '1.60G', 'Quality:': '1080p','Frame Rate:':'23.976 fps','Language:':''}
```

Any help on fixing the issue will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You're zipping two lists together so it's gonna match the first result in `title` and with the first in `result` up to the length of the smallest list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through the elements inside `dl`.  If the current element is `dt` and the next element is `dd`, then store the value as the next element, else set the value as empty string.

```
dl = soup.select('.movie_middle dl')[0]
elems = dl.find_all()  # Returns the list of dt and dd
data = {}
for i, el in enumerate(elems):
    if el.name == 'dt':
        key = el.text.replace(':', '')

        # check if the next element is a `dd`
        if i < len(elems) - 1 and elems[i+1].name == 'dd':
            data[key] = elems[i+1].text
        else:
            data[key] = ''
```

Answer (score 1):

```
from collections import defaultdict 
test = soup.text.split('\n')   
d = defaultdict(list)
for i in range(len(test)):
     if (':' in test[i]) and (':' not in test[i+1]):
         d[test[i]] = test[i+1]
     elif ':' in test[i]:
         d[test[i]] = ''


d
defaultdict(list,
            {'Frame Rate:': '23.976 fps',
             'Genres:': '',
             'Language:': '',
             'Quality:': '1080p',
             'Resolution:': '1920*1080',
             'Size:': '1.60G'})
```

The logic here is that you know that every key will have a colon. Knowing this, you can write an `if else` statement to capture the unique combinations, whether that is `key` followed by `key` or `key` followed by `value`

#### Edit:

In case you wanted to clean your keys, below replaces the  `:` in each one:

```
d1 = { x.replace(':', ''): d[x] for x in d.keys() }
d1
{'Frame Rate': '23.976 fps',
 'Genres': '',
 'Language': '',
 'Quality': '1080p',
 'Resolution': '1920*1080',
 'Size': '1.60G'}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BeautifulSoup` to parse the `dl` structure, and then write a function to create the dictionary:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup 
import re
def parse_result(d):
  while d:
    a, *_d = d
    if _d:
      if re.findall('\<dt', a) and re.findall('\<dd', _d[0]):
        yield [a[4:-5], _d[0][4:-5]]
        d = _d[1:]
      else:
        yield [a[4:-5], '']
        d = _d
    else:
      yield [a[4:-5], '']
      d = []

print(dict(parse_result(list(filter(None, str(soup(content, 'html.parser').find('dl')).split('\n')))[1:-1])))
```

Output:

```
{'Genres:': '', 'Resolution:': '1920*1080', 'Size:': '1.60G', 'Quality:': '1080p', 'Frame Rate:': '23.976 fps', 'Language:': ''}
```

For a slightly longer, although cleaner solution, you can create a decorator to strip the `HTML` tags of the output, thus removing the need for the extra string slicing in the main `parse_result` function:

```
def strip_tags(f):
  def wrapper(data):
     return {a[4:-5]:b[4:-5] for a, b in f(data)}
  return wrapper

@strip_tags
def parse_result(d):
  while d:
    a, *_d = d
    if _d:
      if re.findall('\<dt', a) and re.findall('\<dd', _d[0]):
        yield [a, _d[0]]
        d = _d[1:]
      else:
        yield [a, '']
        d = _d
    else:
      yield [a, '']
      d = []

print(parse_result(list(filter(None, str(soup(content, 'html.parser').find('dl')).split('\n')))[1:-1]))
```

Output:

```
{'Genres:': '', 'Resolution:': '1920*1080', 'Size:': '1.60G', 'Quality:': '1080p', 'Frame Rate:': '23.976 fps', 'Language:': ''}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that empty elements are not present. Since there is no hierarchy between the `<dt>` and the `<dd>`, I'm afraid you'll have to craft the dictionary yourself.

```
vault = {}
category = ""
for item in soup.find("dl").findChildren():
    if item.name == "dt":
        if category == "":
            category = item.text
        else:
            vault[category] = ""
            category = ""
    elif item.name == "dd":
        vault[category] = item.text
        category = ""
```

Basically this code iterates over the child elements of the `<dl>` and fills the `vault` dictionary with the values.